# Unable to get a value from url

Tags: php

Unable to get a value from url.

```
localhost/ddd.php?udh=%05%00%03%6d%03%01
```

When I try to copy paste this url to address bar "localhost/ddd.php?udh=%05%00%03%6d%03%01" it converts to  "http://localhost/ddd.php?udh=%05%00%03m%03%01"
Is there any explanation?

Also I am not able to get $_GET['udh'], it prints:

```
array (size=1)
  'udh' => string '�m' (length=6)
```

Comment: Take a look at `urlencode()` and `urldecode()`

Comment: urlencode($_GET['udh']) prints "%05%00%03m%03%01" insread of "%05%00%03%6d%03%01"

Comment: You don't need to encode the URL explicitly. Browsers take care of encoding certain characters in the URL automatically. Here, you only need to decode the URL. Only decode the URL with `urldecode()`. `urldecode($_GET['udh'])` is alone enough.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should encode your message using `urlencode()` and when accessing the message using `$_GET` you have to decode it using `urldecode()`.

**HTML**

```
<a href ="localhost/ddd.php?udh=".<?php urlencode('message');?>></a>
```

**PHP**

```
$value = urldecode(isset($_GET['udh']));
```

Comment: You don't need to encode the URL explicitly. Browsers take care of encoding the URL automatically. Here, you only need to decode the URL.

Answer (score 0):

From W3C Schools:

> URL Encoding (Percent Encoding)
>   URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the ASCII character-set.
>
> Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.
>
> URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.
>   URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

So when you put the string `%05%00%03%6d%03%01` in the browser it automatically tries do decode it searching for %character, in your case it happens that %6d = m.

Not sure if you are using % as a separator but you could change to : or | and use explode to extract it (http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)